# How to align multiple lines of JOptionPane output dialog messages by ":"?

Tags: java, swing, string-formatting, joptionpane, showdialog

I need to make the output in 3 lines and also aligned by ":", using JOptionPane.showdialogmessage():
*note the alignment of the ":"

```
Total  cost        : $11175.00
Number of units    : 500
Cost per unit      : $22.35
```

I have tried manually adding spaces before each ":" but still these 3 lines do not strictly align:

```
        String output = String.format("Total manufacturing cost                  :$%.2f\n", manufactCost) + 
                String.format("Number of units manufactured       : $%d\n", numManufacted) + 
                String.format("Cost per unit                                         : $%.2f\n", unitCost);
                
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```

Here is the output screenshot:

[image]

What is the easiest way to realize this alignment?
Thanks

P.S.: This is my first post. Sorry, I am still struggling with how to edit the post in a way that shows you the correct format of the output...I have been driven crazy by formatting... so I just post the screenshots instead... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using monospaced fonts, or strange tricks.
Construct a `JPanel` which uses a `GridBagLayout`, and remember `showMessageDialog` accepts other `Component`s, not only text.

[image]

Relevant code. I opted for a separated label for `:` so that you can customize it as you prefer, while still keeping it aligned.

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

final GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
final Insets descriptionInsets = new Insets(3, 5, 3, 15);
final Insets valuesInsets = new Insets(3, 2, 3, 2);

gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
gc.insets = descriptionInsets;
gc.weightx = 1.0;
panel.add(new JLabel("Total cost"), gc);

gc.insets = valuesInsets;
gc.weightx = 0;
gc.gridx = 1;
panel.add(new JLabel(":"), gc);

gc.gridx = 2;
panel.add(new JLabel("$11175.00"), gc);

gc.insets = descriptionInsets;
gc.weightx = 1.0;
gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 1;
panel.add(new JLabel("Number of units"), gc);

gc.insets = valuesInsets;
gc.weightx = 0;
gc.gridx = 1;
panel.add(new JLabel(":"), gc);

gc.gridx = 2;
panel.add(new JLabel("500"), gc);

gc.insets = descriptionInsets;
gc.weightx = 1.0;
gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 2;
panel.add(new JLabel("Cost per unit"), gc);

gc.insets = new Insets(3, 2, 3, 2);
gc.weightx = 0;
gc.gridx = 1;
panel.add(new JLabel(":"), gc);

gc.gridx = 2;
panel.add(new JLabel("$22.35"), gc);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, panel);
```

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean it can not be solved in JOptionPane.showdialogmessage()? I may be wrong but I think it is a string formatting problem, it is?

Comment: @luhaoGeopy if you look at the code I solved it with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`, however I haven't passed in a `String`, but another `JPanel` with a special layout.

Comment: @luhaoGeopy you cannot build a `String` and obtain the correct layout, as each font is different and each system is different.

Comment: @luhaoGeopy let me know if you need clarifications. In case you don't, remember to accept the answer

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the text of the label to start with `"<html>"` then the text will be interpreted as very basic, early HTML. So you can insert a table, or some other alignment.

Answer (score 0):

If the a mono-spaced font is acceptable:

1. use a `"monospaced"` `Font`  (the default font is not mono-spaced, so alignment is mostly impossible)
2. use `String.format` to format the string as needed

Alternative (my preferred, but not exactly easiest way):
use a `JPanel` as *message* of `JOptionPane`, there you can use a layout manager like `GridBagLayout` (or `GridLayout`, easy to use).

Tom's answer, using HTML, is also easy to use (maybe the easiest solution)

Comment: @luhaoGeopy - I edited your question to format the output - just one option of how to do it - eventually you could remove the image (and edit the question as you desire) ((text is better posted as such, not (only) as image - the dialog image is good to stay IMO))

Comment: Thank you for the formatting of my post! I learned sth new